# Calculating $I = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}dxdp \ xW_0(x-b(t)x_0\sqrt{2},p) $ by shifting the contour.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to calculate the following integral:

$$I = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}dxdp  \ xW_0(x-b(t)x_0\sqrt{2},p) $$

Where $W_0$ is a real valued function, and $b(t)=b_0e^{-i\omega t}$, with $b_0$ real. Also, $W_0$ has the properties:

$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}dxdp  \ W_0(x,p)=1$$
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}dxdp  \ xW_0(x,p)=0$$

It seems to me that the right thing to do is substitute $z = x-b(t)x_0\sqrt{2} $, but then for the $x$-integration the contour shifts from the real axis and I don't exactly remember how to deal with this.

Comment: Does the function $W_0$ contains singularities or branch cuts?

Comment: No, it is a real, bounded function.

Comment: in this case, it shouldn't really matter if you go away from the real axis